# Automatic random URL redirect

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a website on Google Sites, and I want to add a 'random post/page' button. I found this code on GitHub and edited it by putting my own URL's. Everything works according to plan except the code uses cookies, basically you go to the link once, it redirects you to a random URL that you have chosen, and it saves that URL. I want to make it so that it's always random, no cookies. I've tried altering the code but nothing seems to work since I don't know much about code, except for the basics. Could anyone help remove the use of cookies of this code? You can view the code below. Thank you.

**[This is the GitHub code](https://github.com/peterdalle/randomizer/blob/master/randomize.html)**

I tried deleting any code that I thought could be related to the cookies, basically the bottom of the code. The code still worked, but the cookies we're still saving. Like I said, I only know the basics so I was just deleting and praying it would fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can be massively simplified if you don't need the cookie functionality:

```js
const redirectUrls = [
    "http://www.aftonbladet.se/",
    "http://www.dn.se/",
    "http://www.svd.se/",
]

document.location = redirectUrls[Math.floor(Math.random() * redirectUrls.length)]
```